# Cordova / Ionic Callback to file:// giving permission denied errors in xcode

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, callback, rails-api

I have an Ionic App that uses ng_token_auth and devise_token_auth to authenticate with my rails api using facebook.

The project runs fine when executed using ionic serve, however while trying to emulate or run from xcode the callback fails with a "Permission denied" Error.

I've narrowed this down to the fact that the callback uri in ios is essentially file:// rather than a web address.

How do i get rid of this permissions violation? I've tried cordova-plugin-whitelist using wildcards in all keys but still not working.

Does anyone have any clues? Driving me nuts.

EDIT: I have this in my index file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' file: 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com https://cdn.pubnub.com https://pubnub.github.io https://maps.googleapis.com https://js.maxmind.com https://csi.gstatic.com https://ssl.gstatic.com * 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' file: 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

And these in my config.xml for now

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

I see the response from the api as

```
Redirected to file://?auth_token=2NYS8SaPIhydxxuA39IbSA&blank=true&client_id=Qc7GuZ3s6d344L2LkWfuPQ&config=&expiry=1491307425&uid=10152938160630709
```

And then the error in Xcode as:

```
webView:didFailLoadWithError - -1102: You do not have permission to access the requested resource.
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [Content Security Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/) meta tag to your `index.html` which allows the `file://` protocol.

Since iOS 10, UIWebView (the default Webview used by Cordova on iOS) respects the CSP tag and enforces it more strictly than Android.

You'll also need to add the `gap://` protocol, or the `deviceready` event will not fire.

Try a CSP something like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' file: data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Comment: Thanks @DaveAlden, But still not working. I now have the following but still getting the same permissions error:   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com https://cdn.pubnub.com https://pubnub.github.io https://maps.googleapis.com https://js.maxmind.com https://csi.gstatic.com https://ssl.gstatic.com * 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

Comment: Ha, just noticed I missed out the `file:` protocol from my example CSP which is the one you actually need! Sorry about that! I've just edited my answer to add it - try adding `file:` to your default rules right after `'self'`

Comment: Thanks again @DaveAlden, still not working though, i've edited my original question with more info and your snippet above. Any more clues?